# Unable to launch the console to get started with Cloudant NoSQL DB in dedicated bluemix

Tags: ibm-cloud, cloudant

I have created a Cloudant NoSQL DB service in dedicated Bluemix, but when I try to launch the console I got following error on firefox:

> Unable to connect
>   Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at a300873c-d856-4cc4-84c8-d4b7e7f0fe96-bluemix.cloudant.com.

I performed a telnet to above hostname server and 443 port, the connection is refused.

I am using Cisco Anyconnect VPN Client, I have connectivity to other dedicated bluemix services, I am not sure what is blocking the connection

any help, will be really appreciate.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It looks like your local network configuration may be the cause of this. Is it possible for you to ping/visit that URL? (Your link is working correctly for me: http://a300873c-d856-4cc4-84c8-d4b7e7f0fe96-bluemix.cloudant.com/)

Comment: Yes, the ping command replies correctly

`ping a300873c-d856-4cc4-84c8-d4b7e7f0fe96-bluemix.cloudant.com
PING wildcard.cloudant.com (169.54.24.138): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 169.54.24.138: icmp_seq=0 ttl=45 time=72.638 ms
64 bytes from 169.54.24.138: icmp_seq=1 ttl=45 time=88.042 ms`

Comment: Still think the problem is likely a firewall setting on your network.  I suggest opening up a support ticket on Bluemix, and they should be able to get you the help you need.

Comment: I just noticed that this error only happens with `Cloudant NoSQL DB Dedicated`offering service by using `Cloudant NoSQL DB`works correctly, any idea?